# Completely remove <apex:outputText> string if the value is blank

Tags: visualforce, pdf, rendered, outputtext, isblank

I'm using this code now:

```
<apex:outputText rendered="{!NOT(ISBLANK(Description__c))}" value="{!Description__c}"/>
```

But sthis string is between another strings, and when I use this code, I'm getting just a blank string instead of deleting it completely. I don't need a space there. How can I implement it?

P.S. I'm working with `renderAs="pdf"`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can make use of OutputPanel attribute

```
<apex:outputPanel rendered="{!(!ISBLANK(Description__c))}">
   <apex:outputText value="{!Description__c}"/>
</apex:outputpanel>
```

If Description is null/empty this wouldn't be visible/no space would be displayed.

Comment: Thank you. It works!

Answer (score 0):

You could try using an old plain html tag like this

{!Description}

If there's no description, the tag shouldn't show up.